# Case Statement Questions regarding column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following, I have a case statement. I am wondering if it's possible to have three separate columns in this case statement. Obviously, the 'else end' statement provides the 'Dependents', 'Employees', and 'Spouse' in a 'Relationship' column. I am looking to have 'Employee', 'Spouse', and 'Dependent' to be in their own column.

```
select 
    Convert (varchar(6),x.mem_date,112) as IncurMonth,
    e.Meme_lev2 as Group#, 
    e.MEME_GRPN as Groupname, 
    --MONTH(x.mem_date) AS mem_date,
    case when m.mem_rel = '01' then 'Employee'
            when m.mem_rel = '02' then 'Spouse'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '03' then 'Child'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '04' then 'Child/No Financial Resp.'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '05' then 'Step child'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '06' then 'Foster child'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '07' then 'Guardian/POA'
            else 'Dependent' end as Relationship,
    COUNT(*) as "Members/Subscribers"
from Impact.dbo.tbl_mem m
left join Impact.dbo.tbl_meme e on e.MEME_ID1 = m.MEM_ID1
inner join impactwork.dbo.tbl_mmonth x on x.mem_date between convert(varchar(10), e.meme_eff, 101) and convert(varchar(10), e.meme_trm, 101)
where e.MEME_LEV2 IN ('52032')
    and x.mem_date between '01/01/2015' and '03/31/2015'
    and meme_rank='900'
group by 
    e.Meme_lev2, 
    e.MEME_GRPN, 
    Convert (varchar(6),x.mem_date,112),
    case when m.mem_rel = '01' then 'Employee'
            when m.mem_rel = '02' then 'Spouse'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '03' then 'Child'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '04' then 'Child/No Financial Resp.'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '05' then 'Step child'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '06' then 'Foster child'
            --when m.MEM_REL = '07' then 'Guardian/POA'
            else 'Dependent' end 
order by group#, Convert (varchar(6),x.mem_date,112), [members/subscribers] desc




IncurMonth Group# Groupname Relationship Members/Subscribers 
201501 52005 Rosco LABORATORIES Employee 30 
201501 52005 Rosco LABORATORIES Dependent 32 
201501 52005 Rosco LABORATORIES Spouse 14 
201501 52005 Rosco LABORATORIES RETIREE AR Employee 17 
201501 52005 Rosco LABORATORIES RETIREE AR Spouse 6
```

Comment: You can have three columns each which has its own case statement, but I am not sure that is what you want. Could you show a sample of the data as you see it now and then as you want it to be?

Comment: What would be the best way to do that? I am not able to post snippets/pictures of the outcomes of these generated queries as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Post a table of the results, you don;t need a picture.

Comment: a Single case statement can't be used to generate 3 different columns in your output.

Comment: @HLGEM One second. My table is being ridiculous when trying to paste.

Comment: Isn;t that waht you are getting now?

Comment: @HLGEM No. I want to have the Spouse, Employee and Dependent in their own column, replacing relationship. Is that possible?

Comment: yes but do you want them on the same line or different ones as they are right now? DO you need a separate count for each one?

Comment: if you want them on the same line, the code will be much more complicated

Comment: Yes. I need a separate count. The count is fairly simple. It's included in the code in the post. I just want a count for each one in their own individual columns instead of having them grouped in a relationship column. This will reduce the amount of records and scrolling.

Comment: OK your code is about to get more complicated. Are you sure this isn't something you want to do in the application code instead? Pivoting in SQL is a pain and it is subject to break when you add a new type of data that would need a new column, so it is harder to maintain than what you have. Suggest you read about PIVOT in books online and make careful note of the conditions required to pivot

Comment: I will read about PIVOT. I thought there would be an easier way to do this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to do this. Replace your case statement with an aggregate function with a conditional expression as argument (so that you only count the rows matching the expression).

I used `sum` below, but you could just as well use `count`:

```
count(case when m.mem_rel = '01' then m.mem_rel end) 'Employee',
```

also remove the expression from the `group by` clause as you're now using it as an aggregate and should not group by it.

```
select 
    Convert(varchar(6),x.mem_date,112) as IncurMonth,
    e.Meme_lev2 as Group#, 
    e.MEME_GRPN as Groupname, 
    --MONTH(x.mem_date) AS mem_date,
    sum(case when m.mem_rel = '01' then 1 else 0 end) 'Employee',
    sum(case when m.mem_rel = '02' then 1 else 0 end) 'Spouse',
    sum(case when m.MEM_REL NOT IN ('01','02') then 1 else 0 end) 'Dependent',
    COUNT(*) as "Members/Subscribers"
from Impact.dbo.tbl_mem m
left join Impact.dbo.tbl_meme e on e.MEME_ID1 = m.MEM_ID1
inner join impactwork.dbo.tbl_mmonth x on x.mem_date between convert(varchar(10), e.meme_eff, 101) 
                                                         and convert(varchar(10), e.meme_trm, 101)
where e.MEME_LEV2 IN ('52032')
    and x.mem_date between '01/01/2015' and '03/31/2015'
    and meme_rank='900'
group by 
    e.Meme_lev2, 
    e.MEME_GRPN, 
    Convert(varchar(6),x.mem_date,112)
order by group#, Convert(varchar(6),x.mem_date,112), [members/subscribers] desc;
```